# I want to use a single filter based on multiple columns and summarize the result in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, unpivot, summarize

I have a table where a student can have a characteristic associated in multiple columns, like this:

```
Student Cohort 1    Cohort 2    UnitsEarned
A       MESA        GS          25
B       FYE         SBP         18
C       MESA                    30
D       SBP         FYE         24
E       DSPS                    20
F       MESA                    32
G       FYE         MESA        18
H       CTE         SBP         22
I       GS          FYE         21
```

What I want to do is to create a filter that will allow me to select all students with a particular characteristic, like MESA, regardless of which column it falls under.  I then want to be able to summarize the value, like do a count of students or take the average of the units earned in Power BI.

I found some help that had me create a new table and calculate measures and filters which allowed me to get to this point:

```
Student Cohort 1    Cohort 2    UnitsEarned
A       MESA        GS          24
C       MESA                    30
F       MESA                    32
G       FYE         MESA        18
```

The filter only shows students who are identified as MESA.  Is there a way to do this process so that the end product is something like:

```
Cohort  Avg UnitsEarned 
MESA    26
```

I appreciate any feedback you can give.  I tried to unpivot those columns, but then the values I was getting were much different than what they should be.

Thanks

Comment: attach the images directly

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is... I unpivoted the cohort columns and got 26 for MESA. That seems to be the result you want. So, why is unpivoting not working for you?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the unpivot to work.  I think I was just over complicating things.